# Passing an array to a drop down box with JavaScript and Codigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, dom-events

A `$location` variable is defined using sessions with Codeigniter, it can be 'Austin', 'Houston'...etc. Each location offers different tours. Since the `$location` variable is already defined all I need to do is to populate the dropdown box with its available tours at the particular location. The dropdown is part of a form and it will validated at the specif controller. Could anyone please give me some Javascript examples that fill the blanks in my code?

```
   <?php
$location = $this->session->userdata('location');

// javascript goes here to decide which location and what tours to send in an array.
// $options_tour will be the returned array sent to the form_dropdown()

//form ...
$data_tour = 'class="span12"';
$tour = array('style' => 'font-weight:bold;');
echo form_label('Select Tour: ','tour', $tour);
echo form_dropdown('tour', $options_tour, '', $data_tour);
    ?>
```

Comment: How do you plan on moving the PHP array into JavaScript? Is this done via AJAX or are you generating a JavaScript file with PHP, or are you just going to echo a <script> tag into HTML?

Comment: I wan to be able to display $options_tour in the drop down box for the user to choose from. My guess will be Ajax but I am not familiar with it. $locations = array(loc1, loc2...)
 if  ($location = $locations[1]){ //do smtg }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate the form in this manner using JavaScript will require a somewhat roundabout method.

Either create a hidden field for javascript to read from to obtain the $location variable's value, or create an ajax call that retrieves it.

Next you will write a JavaScript function that returns the appropriate values based on the location. Something like:

```
function get_tours( location ){

    var tours = {};

    switch locations {

        case 'Austin':
         tours = { "City Center": { 
                                   "text": "City Center" 
                                   "value": "city_center"
                                  }
                 };
        break;

        //etc...
    }

    return tours;
}
```

If you choose to go with the AJAX method you will need to call this tour option setting function when your AJAX returns with a success.

Now that you have the tours in your JavaScript variable you will need to update the  elements of the  element in the page that was generated by PHP. Something like:

```
function create_tour_options ( tours ){

    var select = document.getElementById('tour');

    for ( tour in tours ){
        tour_option = document.createElement('option');
        tour_option.value = tours['tour']['value'];
        tour_option.text = tours['tour']['text'];
        select.appendChild('tour_option');
    }

    // Probably more efficient to create a new select object 
    // and replace the existing one instead of adding and 
    // removing individual options. 
}
```

Additionally if you're not required to use JavaScript, you could simply write a php function to do the above and return your $options_tour variable. Something like:

```
function get_tours( $location='Austin' ){

    $tours = array();

    switch $location {

        case 'Austin':
            $tours = array( "text" => "City Center" 
                            "value" => "city_center"
                          );
        break;

        //etc...
    }

    return $tours;
}
```

I believe it would be better to use PHP if you can as the options will be generated on the initial page load and will not have to be inserted afterwards.

Also I'm not sure if you're using JQuery or not, so I attempted to use vanilla JavaScript example code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used php just like you said and it worked fine. Although I'd like to learn how to do this using Ajax. Could you please post a sample? Thank you in advance.